# Is there a way to use a mailto: link that includes a timestamp or some sort of unique code?

Tags: html, email, random, timestamp, mailto

I'd like to have a link like so:

```
mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=email&body=TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
MATMSG:TO:example@example.com;SUB:email;Body:TIMESTAMP;;
```

But in the subject line or in the body, I'd like it to include any of these options:

1. A timestamp
2. Sort of message like 'Message number #' which counts the number of times it's been used
3. Any sort of unique random code of gibberish

I was hoping it would be possible to somehow import the contents from another website like [this](http://time.is/) or something. Is there any way to do this using a stand alone link? Ultimately, I'm hoping this link can used with a QR code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance I think there are 2 ways to do that:

- generate the link with javascript:

  ```
  document.write('<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=email_' + new (Date().getTime()) + '"></a>');
  ```
- or generate the link with server side scripting, for example PHP:

  ```
  <?php
      echo "<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=email_".round(microtime(true))."</a>"
   ?>
  ```

Personally I would use javascript, I think it's more appropriate for this kind of stuff.

Edit:

Even better is using a javascript bookmarklet, that way it can be used as a link:

`javascript:location.href='mailto:example@example.com?SUBJECT=Data&BODY=Code:'+new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Thanks @omeinusch for the edit suggestion, was having trouble with this code formatting :)