# Include Timestamp in mailto: subject

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I want to include a timestamp in the subject of a mail. I already found out that I have to use javascript for this, I also found a way to include it, but I have trouble displaying the mail adress on the webpage (nothing is displayed). Below is the code I wrote until now. I think it has to do something with the way I included html in my javascript, but I can't find my error.

```
    <script> 
Document.write('<a href="mailto:example@example.de?subject=This is my subject' + new (Date().getTime())+'">example@example.de</a>);
</script>
```

The snippet of code I used is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163418/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-mailto-link-that-includes-a-timestamp-or-some-sort-of-u) one:

```
document.write('<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=email_' + new (Date().getTime()) + '"></a>');
```

Comment: The *first* letter of the script! JavaScript is case-sensitive! Open the developer tools in your browser and read the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be:

```
'<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=email_' + Date.parse(Date()) + '"></a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be doing this, for two reasons:

- [`mailto` is a out-dated, unreliable and dangerous technique.](https://blog.seibert-media.com/2014/10/06/why-mailto-links-should-be-avoided-on-websites/)
- [`document.write` is not much better.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

It's better to send mails from your webserver which would also solve your subject problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know that mailto is somewhat old, but because of the General Data Protection Regulation in the EU, formulars and other "regalur" contacting methods are a bit difficult to implement, so people are now actually going back to this! This is the reason I was using mailto in the first place!